# How to delay the Drag-Start to combine move and Drag-And-Drop dynamically

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx

I want to provide an application that:

- allows to move images around (here a rectangle)
- if that object is moved out of the working area, start Drag-and-Drop for transfere to other applications

So the javafx DragDetected() would come too soon during the object move on the canvas area, I  suppress the onDragDetected() handling and in the onMouseDragged() handler I tried to convert the MouseDrag event into a Drag event using

```
event.setDragDetect(true);
```

But the onDragDetected() comes never again..... what can I do?

The full sample application is:

```
package fx.samples;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.DataFormat;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragRectangle extends Application {
    Point2D lastXY = null;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane mainPane = new Pane(); 
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Rectangle area = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500 , 500);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 30);
        rect.setFill(Color.RED);
        mainPane.getChildren().add(rect);

        rect.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            System.out.println("Move");
            Node on = (Node)event.getTarget();
            if (lastXY == null) {
                lastXY = new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
            }
            double dx = event.getSceneX() - lastXY.getX();
            double dy = event.getSceneY() - lastXY.getY();
            on.setTranslateX(on.getTranslateX()+dx);
            on.setTranslateY(on.getTranslateY()+dy);
            lastXY = new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
            if (!area.intersects(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY(), 1, 1)) {
                System.out.println("->Drag");
                event.setDragDetect(true);
            } else {
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        rect.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            System.out.println("Drag:"+event);
            if (area.intersects(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY(), 1, 1)) { event.consume(); return; }
            Node on = (Node)event.getTarget();
            Dragboard db = on.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);
            db.setContent(makeClipboardContent(event, on, null));
            event.consume();
        });

        rect.setOnMouseReleased(d -> lastXY = null);
    }

    public static ClipboardContent makeClipboardContent(MouseEvent event, Node child, String text) {
        ClipboardContent cb = new ClipboardContent();
        if (text != null) {
            cb.put(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT, text);
        }
        if (!event.isShiftDown()) {
            SnapshotParameters params = new SnapshotParameters();
            params.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            Bounds b = child.getBoundsInParent();
            double f = 10;
            params.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(b.getMinX()-f, b.getMinY()-f, b.getWidth()+f+f, b.getHeight()+f+f));

            WritableImage image = child.snapshot(params, null);
            cb.put(DataFormat.IMAGE, image);

            try {
                File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("snapshot", ".png");
                LinkedList<File> list = new LinkedList<File>();
                ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null),
                        "png", tmpFile);
                list.add(tmpFile);
                cb.put(DataFormat.FILES, list);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        return cb;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I spend some hours reading the JavaFX sources and playing arround with EventDispatcher etc... its finally easy:

In Short:

Suppress the system drag start proposal in the onMouseDragged() handler and set that flag on your behalf:

```
onMouseDragged(e -> {
    e.setDragDetect(false); // clear the system proposal
    if (...) e.setDragDetect(true); // trigger drag on your own decision
}
```

Long text:

The mechanism to start a DragDetected is consequently using the MouseEvent MOUSE_DRAGGED. The system Drag detection will apply some rules to determine if the current mouse-drag will be interpreted as a drag, here the original code:

```
        if (dragDetected != DragDetectedState.NOT_YET) {
            mouseEvent.setDragDetect(false);
            return;
        }

        if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
            pressedX = mouseEvent.getSceneX();
            pressedY = mouseEvent.getSceneY();

            mouseEvent.setDragDetect(false);

        } else if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {

            double deltaX = Math.abs(mouseEvent.getSceneX() - pressedX);
            double deltaY = Math.abs(mouseEvent.getSceneY() - pressedY);
            mouseEvent.setDragDetect(deltaX > hysteresisSizeX ||
                                     deltaY > hysteresisSizeY);

        }
    }
```

and it set

```
mouseEvent.setDragDetect(true)
```

in the normal MOUSE_DRAG event. That event is passed down and is being processed by all 'down-chain' EventDispatchers... only if this events finally arrives for processing and if the isDragDetect flag is still true, a follow up DragDetected event will be generated.

So I am able to delay the DragDetected by clearing the isDragDetect flag on its way down using an EventDispatcher:

```
        mainPane.setEventDispatcher((event, chain) -> {
            switch (event.getEventType().getName()) {
                case "MOUSE_DRAGGED":
                    MouseEvent drag = (MouseEvent)event;

                    drag.setDragDetect(false);
                    if (!area.intersects(drag.getSceneX(), drag.getSceneY(), 1, 1)) {
                        System.out.println("->Drag down");
                        drag.setDragDetect(true);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return chain.dispatchEvent(event);
        });
```

And if this code decides that a drag condition is reached, it simply sets the flag.

```
      drag.setDragDetect(true);
```

Now I am able to move precisely my objects and start the Drag if they are moved outside the application area.

And after some minutes of thinking: the EventDispatcher is not necessary, all can be done in the onMouseDragged handler...

Full code:

```
package fx.samples;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.DataFormat;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class DragRectangle extends Application {
    Point2D lastXY = null;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane mainPane = new Pane(); 
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Rectangle area = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500 , 500);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 30);
        rect.setFill(Color.RED);
        mainPane.getChildren().add(rect);

        rect.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            System.out.println("Move");
            event.setDragDetect(false);
            Node on = (Node)event.getTarget();
            if (lastXY == null) {
                lastXY = new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
            }
            double dx = event.getSceneX() - lastXY.getX();
            double dy = event.getSceneY() - lastXY.getY();
            on.setTranslateX(on.getTranslateX()+dx);
            on.setTranslateY(on.getTranslateY()+dy);
            lastXY = new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
            if (!area.intersects(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY(), 1, 1)) event.setDragDetect(true);
            event.consume();
        });

        rect.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            System.out.println("Drag:"+event);
            Node on = (Node)event.getTarget();
            Dragboard db = on.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);
            db.setContent(makeClipboardContent(event, on, "red rectangle"));
            event.consume();
        });

        rect.setOnMouseReleased(d ->  lastXY = null);
    }

    public static ClipboardContent makeClipboardContent(MouseEvent event, Node child, String text) {
        ClipboardContent cb = new ClipboardContent();
        if (text != null) {
            cb.put(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT, text);
        }
        if (!event.isShiftDown()) {
            SnapshotParameters params = new SnapshotParameters();
            params.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            Bounds b = child.getBoundsInParent();
            double f = 10;
            params.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(b.getMinX()-f, b.getMinY()-f, b.getWidth()+f+f, b.getHeight()+f+f));

            WritableImage image = child.snapshot(params, null);
            cb.put(DataFormat.IMAGE, image);

            try {
                File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("snapshot", ".png");
                LinkedList<File> list = new LinkedList<File>();
                ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null),
                        "png", tmpFile);
                list.add(tmpFile);
                cb.put(DataFormat.FILES, list);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        return cb;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The event dispatcher works great. And you're right after all, you just need to keep false the drag detected flag until it's true. By the way, you may consider this: `db.setDragView(image, event.getX(), event.getY());`, to allow a smooth transition between the image of the node mouse dragged to the one dragged. Note you can't use scene coordinates out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/DragEvent.html):

> The default drag detection mechanism uses mouse movements with a pressed button in combination with hysteresis. This behavior can be augmented by the application. Each MOUSE_PRESSED and MOUSE_DRAGGED event has a dragDetect flag that determines whether a drag gesture has been detected. The default value of this flag depends on the default detection mechanism and can be modified by calling setDragDetect() inside of an event handler. When processing of one of these events ends with the dragDetect flag set to true, a DRAG_DETECTED MouseEvent is sent to the potential gesture source (the object on which a mouse button has been pressed). This event notifies about the gesture detection.

your assumption that just enabling `setDragDetect(true)` at some point *after the mousedragged has started* will fire the drag event, does not work.

The reason for that is there is some private `DragDetectedState` flag, that is used to set the drag state at the beginning of the gesture. And once it's already selected, it can't be changed.

So if the event it's not triggered, what you could do is manually trigger it yourself:

```
if (!area.intersects(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY(), 1, 1)) {
        System.out.println("->Drag");
        event.setDragDetect(true);
        Event.fireEvent(rect, new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.DRAG_DETECTED, 0, 0, 0, 0, MouseButton.PRIMARY, 0, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, null));
    }
```

This would effectively trigger a drag dectected event, and `rect.setOnDragDetected()` will be called.

But this is what you will get:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
     Cannot start drag and drop outside of DRAG_DETECTED event handler
at javafx.scene.Scene.startDragAndDrop(Scene.java:5731)
at javafx.scene.Node.startDragAndDrop(Node.java:2187)
```

Basically, you can't combine DragDetected with MouseDragged, since the `startDragAndDrop` method has to be called within a Drag_Detected [event](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/Node.html#startDragAndDrop-javafx.scene.input.TransferMode...-):

> Confirms a potential drag and drop gesture that is recognized over this Node. Can be called only from a DRAG_DETECTED event handler.

So instead of trying to combine two different events, my suggestion is you just use drag detected event, allowing your scene or parts of it to accept the drop, and translating your node there, while at the same time, if the drag&drop leaves the scene, you could drop the file on the new target.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane mainPane = new Pane();

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 30);
    rect.setFill(Color.RED);
    mainPane.getChildren().add(rect);

    Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    rect.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
        Node on = (Node)event.getSource();
        Dragboard db = on.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
        db.setContent(makeClipboardContent(event, on, null));
        event.consume();
    });

    mainPane.setOnDragOver(e->{
        e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
    });

    mainPane.setOnDragExited(e->{
        rect.setLayoutX(e.getSceneX()-rect.getWidth()/2d);
        rect.setLayoutY(e.getSceneY()-rect.getHeight()/2d);
    });
}
```

Comment: "your assumption that just enabling setDragDetect(true) at some point will fire the drag event, does not work." -> It works, if I do that BEFORE the Drag has started due to the hysteresis (If I do it on the first Move event)... so I hoped that it will work also later.

Comment: I already tried with the fireEvent() with the result you also pointed out: Exception "Cannot start drag and drop outside of DRAG_DETECTED event handler" ... (how sad)

Comment: I first implemented the Drag and Drop also internally in my application, but that provides a very bad user feedback, as the dragged icon of the object is immediatle centered, and, if the image is larger, it will be shown scaled down. So the exact placement for the drop is not known to the user. So I decided to start the drag only if the application will be left during move. Thanks for your help, but I still need a solution for this problem.

Comment: @Jens-PeterHaack About the first comment, I've edited my answer to clarify. By "at some point" I meant "at some point after the mousedragged has started", not that it didn't work at all.

Comment: @Jens-PeterHaack Regarding the bad feedback, you can use this: `db.setDragView(image, event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());`, where `image` is already created on `makeClipboardContent`, and the (offsetX, offsetY) is the position (x,y) of the cursor over the image.

Comment: cool, good to know... thanks. But the auto-sclaedown of larger objects is still messy... but anyhow I found the solution (below). :-)