# Java fx change Image size and drag point offset?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I have a few issues with my drag and drop. I have a resized imageview (obj) that I can drag and drop. The problem is when I drag it the cursor is in the middle. I want to change that. I'v tried db.setDragViewOffsetX(); but it doesn't work. Also the image displayed is full size, and since my imageview is resized I want it to match the imageview size but there seem to be no function to resize Image type...

```
           Dragboard db = obj.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            Image sourceImage = obj.getImage();
            content.putImage(sourceImage);
            db.setContent(content);
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using the Drag/Drop for precise image movements in my application. Also the effect, that for large images, the shown Drag/Drop image is scaled down was annoying too. So I decided to move images not using Drag/Drop within my application and change into Drag/Drop transfer mode if the movement left my application area.

See [How to delay the Drag-Start to combine move and Drag-And-Drop dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826988/how-to-delay-the-drag-start-to-combine-move-and-drag-and-drop-dynamically/26831560#26831560) for that approach.

For a solution on the mouse anchor during Drag/Drop:there also is a comment from José Perera about more control on the Drag/Drop image mouse anchor during move...